# Java switches to debug mode but no error is shown in the console

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have an arraylist is of a class type "checker", that stores different objects (float, string etc).

```
ArrayList<checker> VecAtoms;
checker aux=new checker();
aux.atom="C";
aux.x=0f;
aux.y=0f;
aux.z=0f;
VecAtoms.add(aux);
```

At this point (VecAtoms.add(aux);) Java asks to switch to debug mode, but no erros is shown in the console, nor any detail that could help me figure out what happens. How should I solve that?

Comment: Not an answer but in java, the convention is to name Classes with the first letter be capital and variables first letter being lower. You seem to have it backwards. (i.e. `checker` should be `Checker` and `VecAtoms` should be `vecAtoms`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ArrayList<checker> VecAtoms;` is pointing to null.

```
VecAtoms.add(aux);
```

You are operating on `null` reference which results in `NullPointerException`.

Have your arraylist instantiated, example:

```
ArrayList<checker> VecAtoms = new ArrayList<checker>();
```

as well as make sure aux is not pointing to `null`.

Comment: Seems like `aux` would be null also, assuming `aux` is supposed to be `checkeraux`

Comment: Still no sure why eclipse doesn't tell me about the NPE as it does in other cases, but thanks, it works

Comment: already checked, no debug pointer there. anyway, important is that now it works

Comment: @jschoen it was "checker aux", just cleared the space by mistake when I copied

Answer (score 1):

*VecAtoms* could be *null*. better check if it is null before performing anyy operations on it

```
if(VecAtoms!=null) {
  // add it in the list
}
else{
System.out.println("VecAtom is null")
}
```